# How to create automotive application to trigger notifation for overspeed in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-automotive, automotive

I want to create first application to listen car speed without open this application.
It is possible to monitor car speed in background

Comment: Please check out [ask]

Answer (score 1):

To listen to Car speed you need to create an object of [CarPropertyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/hardware/property/CarPropertyManager) and register for change in Car Speed Property value.([PERF_VEHICLE_SPEED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/VehiclePropertyIds#PERF_VEHICLE_SPEED)) using method [registerCallback()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/hardware/property/CarPropertyManager#registerCallback(android.car.hardware.property.CarPropertyManager.CarPropertyEventCallback,%20int,%20float)) present in CarPropertyManager

registerCallback() method requires a Callback in which to receive speed updates, proprty id of Speed(Constant Value: 291504647 (0x11600207) which is mentioned for  PERF_VEHICLE_SPEED in above mentioned link) and rate at which to receive these updates.

Put all code in a service to receive updates in the background.

You can find samples for the Android Automotive application at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/tests/EmbeddedKitchenSinkApp

Comment: You can check some samples for Automotive applications at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/tests/EmbeddedKitchenSinkApp.                                                                                                  
Also, check this for a sample implementation http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/services/Car/tests/EmbeddedKitchenSinkApp/src/com/google/android/car/kitchensink/property/PropertyListAdapter.java.

Comment: Thank you for comment sir . But i currently using android studio so i can't use the code from that link.

Comment: how to use this code in android studio because im using android studio

Comment: Doesn't matter what you use Android Studio or Eclipse, the code will remain. The sample codes mentioned above only provide Java code which can be used to gain familiarity with Android Automotive specific features for which separate packages/ java files are provided under src.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested sample apk with automotive emulator.
My apk contains some services to run some code on background.
when my app is open in emulator, services are running successfully.  But I try to minimize the app  services are stopped automatically.
there any restrictions in automotive os or we need to follow any procedure to use services in our app.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, can you share the  link to access the code?